# XElement.Add with variables

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a short question for you: Is there a way to use variables when adding or creating a new XElement node? I'm doing it the way described in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Here's my code:

```
Root.<svg:g>.First().Add(<text x="Knoten.@x" y="Knoten.@y" contenteditable="true">AktZiffernfolge</text>)
```

However, this just creates some static text. Knoten.@x, Knoten.@y and AktZiffernfolge should be replaced by their values instead. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed expressions with `<%= exp %>`.

See [How to: Embed Expressions in XML Literals (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384752.aspx).

**Example:**

```
Dim Root = <root>
                <g></g>
            </root>

Dim AktZiffernfolge = "1233/23AB"
Dim Knoten = <Knoten x="123" y="567"></Knoten>

Root.<g>.First().Add(<text x=<%= Knoten.@x %> y=<%= Knoten.@y %> contenteditable="true"><%= AktZiffernfolge %></text>)
```

`Root` is now:

```
<root>
  <g>
    <text x="123" y="567" contenteditable="true">1233/23AB</text>
  </g>
</root>
```